# Reaching points on the circumference using 2 rotations centered in the circle

Tags: geometry

Please look at the following diagram: [image: Diagram]

What I am trying to find out is for a given R1 radius for circle A can we find:

1. Distance between centres A and B
2. Fixed value for radius R2
3. Fixed value for radius R3

such that we can we can draw BCD (blue and red) where C can be any point on the circumference of the circle with centre B and D any point on a circumference of a circle centred at A.

In a real world scenario, would it be possible to have a servo (motor) centred at B with a rotating arm sweeping the circumference of the circle centred at B and having another servo mounted on the edge (C) with another arm sweeping the circumference of the circle centred at C such that *if we aren't already there* we can reach any point of the right half of the big circle centred at A if we rotate one or more servos.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Make sure to read the posting guidelines before asking a question, such as inserting the image in rather than posting a link, formatting with LaTeX, and other such quality of life things.

Comment: I was not able to insert the image.

Comment: @questionasker People need to have a certain reputation before they can post images

Comment: The only requirement is that $R_2+R_3=R_1+AB$